# OAuth2RestTemplate with Ribbon + Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon, oauth2resttemplate

I am working on microservices with Spring Cloud and Netflix OSS Eureka and Ribbon. I have another service running as oauth-server which provides OAuth2 token. All my microservices are registered with Eureka including oauth-server.
My whole solution works if I use hardcoded url of oauth-server as "clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("http://localhost:9000/oauth/token");"
but when I try to use Eureka Discovered url of oauth-server like "clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("http://oauth-server/oauth/token");" I get error:
java.net.UnknownHostException: oauth-server

MyConfig.java

```
@Bean(name = "myOauth2RestTemplate")
@LoadBalanced
public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate(RestTemplateCustomizer customizer,
                                             ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails) {
    OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails);
    ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider provider = new ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider();
    restTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(provider);
    customizer.customize(restTemplate);
    return restTemplate;
}

@Bean
public ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails() {
    ClientCredentialsResourceDetails clientCredentialsResourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("http://oauth-server/oauth/token");
    clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setId("1");
    clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setClientId("candy");
    clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setClientSecret("123");    
    clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setScope(Arrays.asList("read", "write"));
    clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setGrantType("client_credentials");
    return clientCredentialsResourceDetails;
}
```

MyController.java

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myOauth2RestTemplate")
@LoadBalanced
private OAuth2RestTemplate myOauth2RestTemplate;

@GetMapping("/secure/hello")
public String getSecureData() {
    String result = myOauth2RestTemplate.getForObject("http://securems/secure/hello", String.class);
    return result;
}
```

I have searched through a lot of documentation and online help, but those solutions didn't work.
I thought this should have been an easy configuration issue has now eaten up my two days of effort.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to make it work with following code:

```
@Bean
@LoadBalanced
public OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate(SpringClientFactory clientFactory) {
    OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails());
    RibbonLoadBalancerClient ribbonLoadBalancerClient = new RibbonLoadBalancerClient(clientFactory);
    LoadBalancerInterceptor loadBalancerInterceptor = new LoadBalancerInterceptor(ribbonLoadBalancerClient);
    ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider();
    accessTokenProvider.setInterceptors(Arrays.asList(loadBalancerInterceptor));
    restTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(accessTokenProvider);

    return restTemplate;
}
```